# structuring books content in JSON

Tags: json

I am new to programming and building a book reading app.
In this app, I need to remember the sentence a reader read before logging off.

I've been having trouble with the following structure as I cannot do:

var lastSentence = chapter.page.sentence.text

```
"chapter": [
  {
    "id": 1,
    "page": [
      {
        "id": 1,
        "picture": "City_Building.png",
        "sentence": [
          {
            "id": 1,
            "text": "Lorem ipsum...",
          },
          {
            "id": 2,
            "text": "Somethin else...",
          }
        ]
      }
    ]
  }
]
```

I want to try the following, but I am not sure if its correct as a read I should try to reach as flat as a structure as possible:

```
"chapter": [
  {
    "1": [
      {
        "page": [
          {
            "1": [
              {
                "picture": "City_Building.png",
                "sentence": [
                  {
                    "1": [
                      {
                        "text": "Lorem ipsum..."
                      }
                    ]
                  },
                  {
                    "2": [
                      {
                        "text": "Something else..."
                      }
                    ]
                  }
                ]
              }
            ]
          }
        ]
      }
    ]
  }
]
```

this will allow me to do:

```
var lastSentence = chapter.1.page.1.sentence.2.text
```

This structure doesn't go too deep, but still I am looking for a better approach.

Any suggestion?

Comment: Did you attempt to write any code that does what you are trying to do? Where's the code you are having trouble with?

Comment: yes, but I didn't think that sharing it would have solved my problem. I have so far found a work around recreating a flat structure in store.vue, but I grew unsatisfied with the solution and was wondering how I should have structured the file in the first place. I think I got my answer below: it was not a problem of the json structure, rather how I was accessing the objects: I didn't think to do chapter.page.sentence[index].text due to inexperience.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't do 
`var lastSentence = chapter.page.sentence.text` 
because `sentence` in your structure is an array, so when you want to access `text` property, you need to specify the index: `chapter.page.sentence[index].text`

If you want to get text from the latest sentence, you can use `.length` property of array.

`var lastSentence = chapter.page.sentence[chapter.page.sentence.length - 1].text`

Note, that I used `length - 1` because array indexes start from 0, e.g. Array `[1, 2, 3]` has 3 elements with indexes `0, 1, 2`

Comment: Thank you, this is what I was looking for!

Answer (score 2):

What I think about better approach is:

```
{
    "author": "No Name",
    "title": "Wonderful Journey",
    "publishedDate": "17-03-2019",
    "country": "German",
    "city": "Berlin",
    "publisher": "Publisher Name",
    "chapters": [
        {
            "id": 1,
            "title": "Journey Begin",
            "pages": [
                {
                    "id": 1,
                    "picture": "City_Building.png",
                    "content": "Something else...",
                    "footnote": "Something important..."
                },
                {
                    "id": 2,
                    "picture": "City_Building.png",
                    "content": "Something else...",
                    "footnote": "Something important..."
                }
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

You can save it as **JSON file** like **book.json** and call JSON file from Javascript like this:

```
var book = undefined,
    getBook = new XMLHttpRequest();

getBook.onreadystatechange(function() {
    if(this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {
        book = JSON.parse(this.responseText);

        // get author of book
        console.log(book.author);

        // get content of chapter 1 page 1
        console.log(book.chapters[0].pages[0].content);

        // get footnote of chapter 1 page 2
        console.log(book.chapters[0].pages[1].footnote);
    };

getBook.open('GET', 'book.json');
getBook.send();
```

For information about ajax you can follow this [link](https://www.w3schools.com/xml/ajax_intro.asp).

Comment: thank you. I will not be using AJAX but I get the answer I needed from your solution.